# Components called by API won't render

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an app in React. I'm new to React so please bear with me. This question is very simple. I am creating three components that are being called by an API (I'm using axios to call the API), but they simply won't render. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Temperature extends Component {
  showTemperature = () => {
    let apiKey = "4cc79448ae57aa2b8557ec4dcd604fac";
    let city = "Lisbon,pt";
    let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`;
    axios.get(url).then(function(response) {
      let temp = Math.round(response.data.main.temp);
      return temp;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.showTemperature()}</div>;
  }
}

export default Temperature;
```

and then I call the component on App.js

```
<div>
   <Temperature />
</div>
```

inside the App function. Nothing is rendering when I call the component. Any tips or what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

PS: I am importing the components into App:

```
import Temperature from "./Temperature";
```

**EDIT: I want to add that I have this same app done in vanilla JavaScript and the API is working fine.**

Comment: Have you tried rendering some plain text to see if it's an issue with your api call?

Comment: I have tried plain text, it renders fine!

Comment: Well, you should be utilizing state first of all. You should initialize a state variable for temperature, than utilize setState in order to store the value of the api call into your state. Then you would call state in place of this.showTemperature()

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!

Comment: @mfs There is a problem with API key, it gives this response like `{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}` upon trying url (https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$Lisbon,pt&appid=$4cc79448ae57aa2b8557ec4dcd604fac&units=metric)

Comment: You have to remove the $ from the parameters, like so https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lisbon,pt&appid=4cc79448ae57aa2b8557ec4dcd604fac&units=metric it's working normally, this is why I don't understand why my call isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing state to store your temperature value, like so:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Temperature extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         temp: 'Error' // Add default value to help determine if error is api call.
      };

      this.showTemperature = this.showTemperature.bind(this); // Bind 'this' context
   }
showTemperature() {  // This is how to properly declare a method in react.
   let apiKey = "4cc79448ae57aa2b8557ec4dcd604fac";
   let city = "Lisbon,pt";
   let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
   q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`;
   axios.get(url).then(function(response) {
   let temp = Math.round(response.data.main.temp);
   if (temp) { // Don't setstate if temp is undefined.
      this.setState({temp: temp}); // Set your state
   }
 });
};

componentDidMount() {
   this.showTemperature(); // Call your method on mount.
}

render() {
return <div>{this.state.temp}</div>;
  }
}

export default Temperature;
```

I added comments to explain further errors in your code. You should be able to troubleshoot much better from here.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. However I get an error after compiling "TypeError: Cannot set property 'temp' of undefined", with the line `this.state.temp = ' ';`

Comment: @mfs my apologies, I edited the code with fix, I used improper syntax

Comment: thanks so much for your effort. It's still not rendering, which means this is probably a problem with the API rather than a code problem

Comment: @mfs I would agree :) Nonetheless I recommend that you adopt this coding pattern.

Comment: I used the default value, and it renders without a problem, so the problem is with the API call. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've edited the code & you can find the same in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-won4z)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import Temperature in App.js like this

```js
import Temperature from 'path'
```

Comment: What do you mean? I am importing Temperature into App like this `import Temperature from "./Temperature";`

Comment: Yeah! Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Your showTemperature method returns undefined. That's why It's not rendering anything.